# Maven - Build a specific project in a multi-module project

Tags: java, maven

I found many SO answers which redirects me to `reactor plugin`. But [Maven page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-reactor-plugin/) says `This Plugin is retired`. What are other alternatives for this purpose?

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: Don't use reactor plugin. In Maven 3.X you can use `mvn -pl moduleToBuild` plus `--amd` which mean `--also-make-dependents`...

Answer (score 3):

Try executing:

```
mvn -pl :subprojectToBeBuilt
```

By calling Maven help (`mvn -h`) you can see its documentation:

```
$ mvn -h
[...]
-pl,--projects <arg>   Comma-delimited list of specified
                       reactor projects to build instead
                       of all projects. A project can be
                       specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                       or by its relative path.
```

Comment: You should use `mvn -pl moduleToBuild`. Don't use the `:`.

Comment: @khmarbaise well, it depends on how you specify the project that you would like to build. As stated by the documentation (see my answer above), you use `:` if you target the specific artifact based on its artifact id. Without `:`, you target the artifact by its relative path. Depending on your project structure, they may be the same (if the artifact is located in a direct subfolder that has the same name as the artifact id), but they can also differ.

Comment: Hi, [I am missing something here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723160/build-a-single-module-in-maven-multi-module-project) Can you please help? It is exactly related to this.